# How to add string to a ModelSerializer in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my database, I  store the file name of a particular image for an item. Let's say this is the model in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(validators=[isalphanumeric], max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
```

and then I have a serializer defined like so in `serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

what I want is to be able to add a string to the image of a `Product` that makes it into a string representing the relative link, something like:

```
storage_location = '/assets/img'
img_url = f'{storage_location}/{image}'
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I want to be flexible with the urls rather than having the file name be a "file location" and then having to update the database each time I change how I arrange my images (I'm still not sure how to store them).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can use model's [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) for this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(validators=[isalphanumeric], max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=20, blank=False)
```

This will automatically add [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-url) setting to the value when you fetch value.

In case you want to use `CharField` you can do what you need on serializer level using [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class ProductSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_image(self, obj):
        storage_location = '/assets/img'
        img_url = f'{storage_location}/{obj.image}'
        return img_url

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following in your `serialiser.py`

```
class ProductSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
     img_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
     class Meta:
          model = Product
          fields = '__all__' 
          #fields = ('sku', 'img_url') # This is what i will prefer
     def get_img_url(self, obj):
         storage_location = '/assets/img'
         img_url = f'{storage_location}/{obj.image}'
         return img_url
```

Good Luck!