# Understanding Image Fields, MEDIA_ROOT & MEDIA URL

Tags: python, django, django-models

Building of [neverwalkaloner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125819/how-to-add-string-to-a-modelserializer-in-django-rest/52125870#52125870)'s answer here, I tried migrating my image model attribute from a CharField to an ImageField and then setting `MEDIA ROOT` & `MEDIA URL` in `settings.py`.

My understanding, reading the documentation:

[here (how Django handles files)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/files/),

[here (what does MEDIA URL and MEDIA ROOT mean)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT),

and [here (what ImageField is and its different arguments)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField), Django will handle the absolute path to the file of the particular `ImageField` based of the `upload_path` & settings. So I tested it in the shell. So far, it isn't working.

**UPDATED ATTEMPT AT PRODUCT**

In `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/project' + '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(validators=[isalphanumeric], max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/" max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
```

Testing it out in the Python Django shell:

```
In  [1]: from app.models import Product
In  [2]: test_product = Product(sku='alphanumeric23', image='test_product.png')
In  [3]: test_product.image.path
Out [3]: 'C:\\Users\\user\\path\\to\\project\\project\\media\\test_product.png'
```

But my expected output should have been:

```
'C:\\Users\\user\\path\\to\\project\\project\\media\\product\\test_product.png'
```

Why am I not getting the correct url path?

Is it because it hasn't *technically* been uploaded with a test_product.save() call?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your model has a charfield, not an imagefield. And what is log?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add `max_length` in in `ImageField`.
If you want a proper url path you can set the code something like this :

urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/path/to/projectdirectory/media/"
```

some.html:

```
{{product.image.url}}
```

Output url : `https://hostname/media/products/image.jpg`
You can also add `upload_to= 'products/%Y/%m/%d'` 
if you want an output as this :

```
https://hostname/media/products/year/month/date/image.jpg
```

Comment: I tried editing the project urls.py to include the code you suggested but it still didn't append the "products/" into the media image.

Comment: You should add the code at the bottom of the urls.py. Maybe change `MEDIA_ROOT` as i stated. There is no way that you save your image under `products/` folder but only get image name in url. `MEDIA_ROOT` is like `/hostname/media/` and when you click image as saved `products/image.png` the paths linked as this : `hostname/media/products/image.png`.